# Flex: fx:Script vs. fx:Declarations

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe, flash-builder

What is the difference between `<fx:Script>` and `<fx:Declarations>`? Do I need both, or is one the new replacement of the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Script is a place to put some AS3 code onto the MXML class.  Declarations are a way to put public properties defined in MXML on a class.